# Is there any way I can ssh from my machine into windows 8/10 Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, virtualbox, remote-access

I have a gentoo setup as my host on which I have setup virtual box. On virtual box, I have installed windows8 and mac os x.

My question is, is any way I can ssh into windows8 vm and mac os x from my (gentoo)machine? As I'm using vagrant 1.4.3 to start VM, I tried using vagrant ssh command, but it gives an error:

ssh_exchange_identitfication: read: Connection reset by peer

Appreciate your help!

Thanks :)

Comment: what have you tried?, i could easy say three or four steps to archieve this but i dont know what have you done.

Comment: Dana / user503806 (if you are the same person): It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://superuser.com/users/503806/user503806 and http://superuser.com/users/503807/dana.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on and accept answers to this question.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia I tried using vagrant ssh command, but it gives an error: ssh_exchange_identitfication: read: Connection reset by peer

Comment: on most versions of windows SSH is a pain. have you considered the rdesktop package instead to connect to RDP? http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdesktop  The next version of windows server is supposed to natively support SSH, which will be great, but until then....

Answer (score 2):

You can install Cygwin and activate OpenSSH inside. There is a [documentation at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC281) on how to do it. Keep in mind, it's not the most popular way to access a Windows machine -- most users would use RDP for doing it.